# How to check php.ini syntax on ubuntu / nginx

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I have problems with setting the upload_max_filesize in my php.ini. I get no errors when I restart my php5-fpm and / or nginx service but I still suspect this to be a problem of the php.ini syntax.

But how can I check the syntax of the php.ini on my server?

Comment: Check the error logs and the message when you start your service. What is the error you get?

Comment: I dont get any errors? Or are errors logged silently?

Comment: Is there something under `/var/log/nginx/`, there are many causes for why you don't get a log, maybe [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-logging-and-log-rotation-in-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-vps) could help you find something useful. Doesn't the service manager tell you something when the service fails to start? does it even fail or does it start correctly?

Comment: Don't forget you have to increase POST size too.